# How to prove that $\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{8}+\sqrt[3]{7}<3$?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

How to prove that $\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{8}+\sqrt[3]{7}<3$ without using calculus/high school methods or routine calculation of the roots with the precision needed? The difference between them is close enough to $0$, so trivial estimations like $\sqrt{15}<4$ or $\sqrt[3]{7}<2$ don't help here. What else can we try?

Comment: Maybe you could try to compare the binomial expressions of $(\sqrt{15}+\sqrt[3]{7})^n$ and $(\sqrt{8}+3)^n$ for some $n$ big enough

Comment: $\sqrt{8}-\sqrt[3]{7}<\sqrt{8+1}-\sqrt[3]{7+1}=\sqrt{9}-\sqrt[3]{8}=1$ (since increasing 1 in the square root has more investment than in the $\sqrt[3]{}$), then your inequality becomes $\sqrt{15}<4$

Comment: @Mher Wrong side, it's not equivalent

Comment: Is using continued fraction a bad idea ?

Comment: It may help if you take a 2 out of the square roots and divide both sides by 2, then you get

$$
1.5 + \sqrt{2} > \sqrt{3.75} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{8}}
$$

You know that $\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{8}} < 1$ may be helpful

Comment: @Exodd: which side is wrong, about what equivalence do you mean, there is no such thing. Actually, I checked all my steps by calc.

Comment: @Mher You're saying $-\sqrt{8}+\sqrt[3]{7}> -1$ and $\sqrt{15}<4$, but these don't sum up to the thesis

Comment: @Exodd: ok, I see now, I doens't finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $15<(4-\frac 18)^2$ and $7<(2-\frac{1}{12})^3$, while $8>(3-\frac 15)^2$. Also, $\frac15-\frac18-\frac{1}{12}$ is negative. The result follows.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Though your inequalities are not very easily checked by hand (especially the second one), and it's not very clear how to invent it. I hope that there is more natural approach...

Comment: @CuriousGuest: For the second one, you have to calculate the cube of $23$ and compare it with $7$ times the cube of $12$; this can be done on paper reasonably easily. Of course, I didn't derive it this way: I used the formula $(a-b)^3=a^3-3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$ with $a=2$ and $b$ chosen to make the first two terms add to $7$. The basic idea is to use rational approximations that are as simple as possible. I'm sorry, but I can't see any simpler ones.

Comment: @CuriousGuest I would say that they are in fact easily checked by hand (and even mentally). For the second one, we have $$(2-\frac1{12})^3 = 2^3 - 3\cdot2^2\cdot\frac1{12} + 3\cdot2\cdot\frac1{12^2} - \frac1{12^3} = 8 - 1 + \frac1{24} - \frac1{1728} > 7.$$
Apart from $12^3$, by cancelling fractions, the biggest number that comes up is $24$, and then it's clear without calculating $12^3$ that $\frac1{24} - \frac1{12^3} > 0$.